# CheckBox checked automatically in ListView when scrolling the list

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

I'm using a `ListView` in my app which contains some elements like textboxes and `CheckBox` in each list item. When I fill the first textbox the seventh one or any other random *textbox automatically filled* with the *same value*  and same happens with `CheckBox` when I *checked* the *CheckBox* any other random CheckBox is also **checked automatically**.

I'm unable to figure it out why it happens.

**My code below:**

Listview content

```
<!--- add your MY problem code comment -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/hyList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="35sp"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tbltab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="100" >    
        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/rowfooter"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35sp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" >    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_Hy_ID"
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="35sp"
                android:textSize="1pt" >
            </TextView>    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_HyID"
                android:layout_width="0sp"
                android:layout_height="35sp"
                android:textSize="1pt" >
            </TextView>    
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_Hy_Area"
                android:layout_width="200sp"
                android:layout_height="35sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:textSize="8pt" >
            </TextView>    
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chkHyCondition"
                android:layout_width="60sp"
                android:layout_height="35sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:saveEnabled="true" />    
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTxtHyRemarks"
                android:layout_width="120sp"
                android:layout_height="35sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:maxLength="25"
                android:saveEnabled="true"
                android:textSize="8pt" >
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

and Listview

```
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/ListViewHy"
   android:layout_width="420sp"
   android:layout_height="100sp"
   android:layout_column="0"
   android:layout_span="3"
   android:clickable="true"
   android:saveEnabled="true"
   android:scrollbarSize="10sp"
   android:scrollbars="vertical" >
   </ListView>
```

I'm using this to bind my listview:

```
private void FillGridHygiene() {
    LstViewHy = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewHy);
    clsDatabase dbh = new clsDatabase(this);
    dbh.openDataBase();
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = dbh.getGridData("030");
    dbh.close();
    if (cursor != null) {
        int cnt = cursor.getCount();
        if (cnt > 0) {
            startManagingCursor(cursor);
            try {
                // -----------BindingListView----------------------------------------------------------------------------

                SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                        R.layout.hygiene_list, cursor, new String[] {
                                Audit_FSD_Tab.KEY_ROW_ID,
                                Audit_FSD_Tab.KEY_ID,
                                Audit_FSD_Tab.KEY_SHORT_NAME }, new int[] {
                                R.id.txt_Hy_ID, R.id.txt_HyID,
                                R.id.txt_Hy_Area });
                adapter.setViewResource(R.layout.hygiene_list);
                LstViewHy.setAdapter(adapter);
                LstViewHy.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                LstViewHy.setFocusable(false);
                LstViewHy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.fillInStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Edit :1**

**API Level - 7
version - 2.1**

Comment: listview recycle its view. you should use your custom adapter

Comment: Thanks but would you like to guide me that how i could achive it

Comment: see these http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/ ,http://blog.cluepusher.dk/2009/11/16/creating-a-custom-cursoradapter-for-android/,http://stackoverflow.com/a/5300871/985143

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the design of your listview. You need to create a Custom Adapter and with the help of view holder and convertview recycle your views. Listview [List view using baseadapter](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)

This will help you in understanding the ListView concept and give an idea why - other random textbox automatically filled with the same value and same happens with checkbox when i checked the checkbox any other random checkbox is also checked automatically. Hope this will help you and help in designing your listview

Comment: view holder not available for 2.1

Comment: ViewHolder is a user defined class. Its not an Android dependent Class

Answer (score 1):

As the other said you'll have to make a custom `Adapter` and proper set/restore the values(for the CheckBox/EditText) for each row in the `bindView`. Below is a simple example of an `Adapter` that stores the state:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

            // this will hold a mapping between the row ids and a special object that  will store the values for the EditText and CheckBox
    private HashMap<Long, StateSaver> status = new HashMap<Long, StateSaver>();

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
                    // get th id of the this row so we can use it as an identifier
        long theId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        CheckBox ckb = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        ckb.setTag(new Long(theId));
                    // store the status of the CheckBox when it changes
        ckb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                Long theRealId = (Long) buttonView.getTag();
                StateSaver obj = status.get(theRealId);
                if (obj == null) {
                    obj = new StateSaver();
                    status.put(theRealId, obj);
                }
                obj.checked = isChecked;
            }
        });
        EditText et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et.setTag(new Long(theId));
                    // when the EditText losses focus it's time to store the value entered by the user
        et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(!hasFocus) {
                    Long theRealId = (Long) v.getTag();
                    StateSaver obj = status.get(theRealId);
                    if (obj == null) {
                        obj = new StateSaver();
                        status.put(theRealId, obj);
                    }
                    obj.currentInput = ((EditText) v).getText().toString();
                }
            }
        });
        StateSaver sv = status.get(theId);
        // setup the row with the correct data, either the default or what you've previously stored
        if (sv == null) {
            ckb.setChecked(false);
            et.setText("");
        } else {
            ckb.setChecked(sv.checked);
            et.setText(sv.currentInput);
        }

    }

    private class StateSaver {
        boolean checked = false;
        String currentInput = "";
    }

}
```

Also you'll want to set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` for the `Activity` containing the `ListView`.

My advice is to avoid using an `EditText` in a `ListView` row.
Also, try to improve your row layout: `sp` units should be used for text sizes only(use `dp` instead in any other places), don't use `pt` units, see if you really need the `layout_weight` attribute etc.