# html tags on sqlite db

Tags: android, html, database, sqlite, tags

I'm italian and I'm new to android language. Please help me and forgive my very bad english.
I need to use html tags (like ) on my sqlite db. 
I insert the words, but they are displayed like they are written (for example "047017661
X").
The code of my page is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

//Android listview object
//  ListView listViewPhoneBook;

    DBAdapter books;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    openDB();
    //---add 2 titles---
    /* if(books.getAllTitles().getCount()==0)*/ {//inserimento dati, solo se il db è vuoto
    long id;
    id = books.insertTitle(
            "047028   &lt;B5818&gt;",
            "C# 2008 Programmer's Reference",
            "Wrox");        
    id = books.insertTitle(
            "0470</br>17661<br/>X",
            "Professional Windows </br>Vista Gadgets Programming",
            "Wrox");}


populateListViewFromDB();}



private void openDB(){
    books = new DBAdapter(this);
    books.open();
}
private void closeDB(){
    books.close();}



    private void populateListViewFromDB() {
        Cursor cursor = books.getAllTitles();


        startManagingCursor(cursor);


        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]
                {DBAdapter.KEY_ISBN};
        int[] toViewIDs = new int []
                {R.id.textView1};


    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this, 
                    R.layout.item_layout,
                    cursor,
                    fromFieldNames,
                    toViewIDs);

    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewFromDB);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Where I have to insert something for decode html tags?
I searched something like "textView.setText(Html.fromhtml" but I don't understand where to put this instruction. Into the file xml? Into the file Java? Can you help me?
In this site I read this posts:
If your data contains only simple HTML tags, they can actually be handled by a TextView by using Html.fromHtml(yourString). That static method returns a Spanned, which can be displayed by a TextView with far less overhead than a WebView.
answered Jan 11 '11 at 4:53
Ian G. Clifton

Sorry, but I don't know where I can put this code. I tried extending TextView but the setText method is set as final. – Kieran Jan 12 '11 at 3:28

You don't need to extend TextView, just pass it the Spanned returned by Html.fromHtml() rather than the String from the Cursor. You can extend the SimpleCursorAdapter and override the setViewText method.

What does it mean for my code above?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/training/notepad/index.html). It may give you a better view of how this works and you would probably prefer to reorganize your code (although I know you are just testing).

END_OF_UPDATE

Change:

```
id = books.insertTitle(
        "0470</br>17661<br/>X",
        "Professional Windows </br>Vista Gadgets Programming",
        "Wrox");}
```

To:

```
id = books.insertTitle(
        Html.escapeHtml("0470</br>17661<br/>X"),
        Html.escapeHtml("Professional Windows </br>Vista Gadgets Programming"),
        Html.escapeHtml("Wrox"));}
```

UPDATE:

At this point, your titles are correctly escaped in your database, so you need to unescape them when you decide to show them. You are using a ListView with a SimpleCursorAdapter, so I would suggest you create a custom adapter for your ListView and use Html.fromHTML:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(StringFromTheCursor), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

CHECK:

- [how do i create a custom cursor adapter for a listview for use with images and text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300787/how-do-i-create-a-custom-cursor-adapter-for-a-listview-for-use-with-images-and-t)
- https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1057/android-custom-cursoradapter-design

END_OF_UPDATE

By the way, check [this](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html) (an old unofficial list of the tags accepted by the TextView).

An alternative (depending on your app's approach) could be using a webview instead of a textview (and ListView) and forget the previous escaping/unescaping solution:

```
WebView mywebview = new WebView(context);
String content = StringFromTheCursor;
mywebview.loadData(content,"text/html","utf-8");
```

SOURCE: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml(java.lang.String)

```
public static String escapeHtml (CharSequence text)

    Added in API level 16
    Returns an HTML escaped representation of the given plain text.

public static Spanned fromHtml (String source)

    Added in API level 1
    Returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string. Any <img> tags in the HTML will display as a generic replacement image which your program can then go through and replace with real images.

    This uses TagSoup to handle real HTML, including all of the brokenness found in the wild.

public static Spanned fromHtml (String source, Html.ImageGetter imageGetter, Html.TagHandler tagHandler)

    Added in API level 1
    Returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string. Any <img> tags in the HTML will use the specified ImageGetter to request a representation of the image (use null if you don't want this) and the specified TagHandler to handle unknown tags (specify null if you don't want this).

    This uses TagSoup to handle real HTML, including all of the brokenness found in the wild.

public static String toHtml (Spanned text)

    Added in API level 1
    Returns an HTML representation of the provided Spanned text.
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! I put alls the codes I have: activity_main.xml<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewFromDB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="342dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

Comment: and item_layout.xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>

Comment: I add this code to mainactivity, but i have problems:  public class TestSetText extends Activity {
         String content = StringFromTheCursor;
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
         @Override
         public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         tv1.setText(Html.fromHtml(StringFromTheCursor), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         }}  it doesn't like stringfromthecursor

Comment: As you didn't include that part of the code (where you got the string from the cursor), I named it StringFromTheCursor, but you must change it to fit your code.

Comment: from dbadapter.java:    //---retrieves all the titles---
    public Cursor getAllTitles() 
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
          KEY_ROWID, 
          KEY_ISBN,
          KEY_TITLE,
                KEY_PUBLISHER}, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null);
    }

Comment: What string I have to use?

Comment: Alejandro, help me, please?

Comment: I think you (we) are messing things up. I gave you a solution with TextView because you talked about it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: OK! I get your message! It means I'll study for days and days for creating a custom adapter. It's been a miracle, for me, create a listview with simpleadapter, and now I have to begin from zero. However i give you great thanks, if sometimes in your life you'll be in Sicily, I'll return the favor! :)

Comment: Don't worry, as everything in life, it's easier than how it looks at the beginning. I made a new update to my answer. If you ever come to Gran Canaria (Canary Islands), feel free to contact me.