# ListAdapter add just one type of data in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

Could someone help me with this? I have two cursor items.

- One to get time data
- and one to get the name of the task out of the database.

But it only sets the task in the ListView. When I delete the task cursor then it sets the Time, but not both at the same time.

I want this as list: time - task name

This is the codepart for it:

```
public void updateUI() {
    helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivityPhone.this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.TIME},
            null, null, null, null, TaskContract.Columns.TIME + " ASC");

    Cursor cursor2 = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
            null, null, null, null, TaskContract.Columns.TIME + " ASC");

    listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.task_view,cursor,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns.TIME, TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
            new int[]{R.id.timeTextView, R.id.taskTextView},
            0
    );



  //  Log.v("Cursor Object", DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor));

 /*   Cursor cursor2 = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
            null, null, null, null, TaskContract.Columns.TIME + " ASC");


  listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this,
            R.layout.task_view,
            cursor2,
            new String[]{TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
            new int[]{R.id.taskTextView},
            0
    );*/

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);





}
```

Comment: You can create own cursoradapter, look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300787/how-do-i-create-a-custom-cursor-adapter-for-a-listview-for-use-with-images-and-t

Comment: I believe you will have to make a custom adapter for this because `SimpleCursorAdapter` takes only one `Cursor` at a time. So, when only one `Cursor` is available to the adapter you can't show data from another `Cursor`.

Comment: use projection `columns` like `TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.TIME, TaskContract.Columns.TASK`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things you could do:

- Create your own cursor adapter, that way you can pass 2 Cursors, and show the data as you like.
- Combine the cursors into one with the data you need, that way you can use the standard adapter.
- Combine the cursors in a String array. so you would get the data you need and save it in strings like: time - task name. Then use an ArrayAdapter to fill the ListView.

I think there is enough code around for all these 3 methods if you google around a bit. I assume the problem is that the current adapter doesn't have the logic to combine both tables.

Answer (score 2):

@Kezufru's answer is correct.
It looks like in your case you can try the second option from his answer. Try something like this:

```
public void updateUI() {
    helper = new TaskDBHelper(MainActivityPhone.this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = sqlDB.query(TaskContract.TABLE,
        new String[]{TaskContract.Columns._ID, TaskContract.Columns.TIME, TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
        null, null, null, null, TaskContract.Columns.TIME + " ASC");


    listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, R.layout.task_view,cursor,
        new String[]{TaskContract.Columns.TIME, TaskContract.Columns.TASK},
        new int[]{R.id.timeTextView, R.id.taskTextView},
        0
);
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
```