# The views are crazy, I use ListView. And all views change

Tags: android, listview

I have a code that every view will have a different background
When I scroll up and down then all the colors get confused and all the `CheckBoxes` markings change and when I erase a part, Then something else is erased and changed color.

tell me if you need The full code

this the code of Changed Background color:

```
View v = List.getChildAt(index -
            List.getFirstVisiblePosition());

    if(v == null)
        return;
    ConstraintLayout LayoutT = v.findViewById(R.id.LayoutT);
    LayoutT.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

this code of delete:

```
 CheckBox currentCheckBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(mCheckBoxView);
    currentCheckBox.setChecked(mCheckBoxStates[csr.getPosition()]);
    currentCheckBox.setTag(new Long(csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_ID))));

    currentCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        final int position = fcsr.getPosition();
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckBoxStates[position] = ((CheckBox) buttonView).isChecked();
            int restore_cursor_position = fcsr.getPosition();
            fcsr.moveToPosition(position);
            fcsr.moveToPosition(restore_cursor_position); //restore the Cursor's position
        }
    }); 
      another class:
 for (long id : mCheckedIdList) {

                mDBHandler.deleteRecord(id);

            }
            db.beginTransaction();
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            db.endTransaction();

            mCsr = mDBHandler.getAllRecords();
            mMCA.swapCursor(mCsr);
```

**EDIT**

I tried to do what you suggested at first. And it worked perfectly but when I adjusted it to my code then only one color appears, it changes depending on the last color or the first one that should appear

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    View convertview = super.getView(position, view,parent);

    parent.setBackgroundColor(0xFF555555);
  //  LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) 
 convertview.findViewById(R.id.item_layout);

    int[] colours = new int[]{ 
            ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.Cyan)
  ,    ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.LowRed)
  };
    if (convertview != null) {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
        int Count = List.getCount();
        String[] Status = new String[Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < Count; ) {
            Cursor c = db.getCursorStatus(i);
            if (c != null) {
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    Status[i] = c.getString(0);

                }
            }

            String mStatus[] = new String[3];
        mStatus[0] = "Monetary_Expenditure";
        mStatus[1] = "Financial income";
        mStatus[2] = "Cancellation";


        boolean first = Status[i] != null && Status[i].equals(mStatus[1]);
        boolean second = Status[i] != null && Status[i].equals(mStatus[0]);

        if (Status[i] != null && Status[i].equals(mStatus[1])) {
            convertview.setBackgroundColor(colours[1]);
        } else if (Status[i] != null && Status[i].equals(mStatus[0])) {
            convertview.setBackgroundColor(colours[0]);
        }
        else {convertview.setBackgroundColor(0xFF555555);}

        i++;
    }
   }
    return convertview;
  }
```

**edit 2**

I changed it:

```
 if (convertview != null) {
    Cursor csr = getCursor(); 
    String status = csr.getString(0);
    int colourindex = 0;
    if (status.equals("Financial income") {
        colourindex = 1;
    }
    if (status.equals("Cancellation") {
        colourindex = 2;
    }
    convertview.setBackgroundColor(colours[colourindex]);       
}
```

to:

```
       if (convertview != null) {
        Cursor csrF = getCursor();

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
         i++;
        Cursor csr = db.getCursorStatus(i);
        String status = csr.getString(0);
        int colourindex = 0;
        if (status.equals("Financial income")) {
            colourindex = 1;
        }
        if (status.equals("Cancellation")) {
            colourindex = 2;
        }
        convertview.setBackgroundColor(colours[colourindex]);
 }
```

Because the cursor did not turn to the right line

And I get this error: `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1`

**EDIT 3**

```
 Cursor csr = getCursor();
        String status="";
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            status = csr.getString(4);
        }
        int colourindex = 3;
        if ("Monetary Expenditure".equals(status)){
        colourindex = 0;
        }
        else if ("Financial income".equals(status)) {
            colourindex = 1;
        }
        else if ("Cancellation".equals(status)) {
            colourindex = 2;
        }
        convertview.setBackgroundColor(colours[colourindex]);
        Log.i("Debug", "colour index is: "+colourindex);
```

Comment: a list view is designed to repeat itself. it would take too much memory on the system to create a BRAND NEW view for each row. with that being said, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to make X layout (array of layout) with the same design: 5 TextField 1 and Checkbox and background color X. Now I want to create some of these layout and put each information in different but the color of the background will be different for each. Sorry if I did not explain myself correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Custom Adapter override the getView() method and set the colour in that method.

The signature is :- `public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)`.

- position is the position within the list of the view being processed.
- view is the view (the layout)
- parent is the ListView
- The modified view should be returned.

An example, that changes the background colour (every x rows is a different colour where x is the number of colours) :-

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    View convertview = super.getView(position, view,parent);

    parent.setBackgroundColor(0xFF555555);
    //LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) convertview.findViewById(R.id.item_layout);

    int[] colours = new int[]{0xFFFF55FF,0xBBFF55FF,0x77FF55FF};
    if (convertview != null) {
        convertview.setBackgroundColor(colours[position % colours.length]);
        //ll.setBackgroundColor(colours[position % colours.length]);
    }
    return convertview;
}
```

- `parent.setBackgroundColor(0xFF555555);` sets the background colour (darkish grey) of the ListView.
- Commented out lines are an alternative means to get get the layout but aren't required
- In this example the colours are the same but the transparency is increases thus letting the background (ListView/parent) colour to show.

The result (as per modification of the code provided in the answer provided to your previous question) :-

[image]

You could alternately override the `bindView` method, as that has the View passed to it, although it does not have the position passed. You could also use a combination of both.

---

#### Another Example of manipulating ListView colours

Here's a completer Custom Cursor Adapter that uses user defined colours extracted from the database to colour each item accordingly using `bindView`. However, this changes the drawable's background colour. It's for Credit Card management (work still in progress ), thus each item in the ListView looks like a Credit Card. :-

```
public class CardListViewCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    Cursor mCurssor;

    CardListViewCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor csr) {
        super(context, csr, 0);
        mContext = context;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor csr, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.standard_cards_listview,
                viewGroup,
                false
        );
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor csr) {

        TextView mCardName = view.findViewById(R.id.scl_cardname);
        TextView mCardNotes = view.findViewById(R.id.scl_cardnotes);
        LinearLayout mCardLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.scl_cardlayout);
        Drawable mDrawable = mCardLayout.getBackground();

        int cardcolour = (int) CardManageActivity.DEFAULT_CARDCOLOUR;

        long extracted_cardcolour = csr.getLong(
                csr.getColumnIndex(
                        DBCardsTableConstants.CARDCOLOUR.getDBColumnName()
                )
        );
        if ((extracted_cardcolour & DBCardsTableConstants.CARDSCOLOUR_FLAG) > 0) {
            cardcolour = (int) extracted_cardcolour;
        }

        setShapeBackGroundColour(mDrawable, cardcolour);

        mCardName.setText(
                csr.getString(
                        csr.getColumnIndex(
                                DBCardsTableConstants.CARDNAME.getDBColumnName())
                )
        );
        mCardNotes.setText(
                csr.getString(
                        csr.getColumnIndex(
                                DBCardsTableConstants.CARDNOTES.getDBColumnName()
                        )
                )
        );
    }

    private void setShapeBackGroundColour(Drawable drawable, int colour) {
        if (drawable instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
            ShapeDrawable sd = (ShapeDrawable) drawable;
            sd.getPaint().setColor(colour);
        }
        if (drawable instanceof GradientDrawable) {
            GradientDrawable gd = (GradientDrawable) drawable;
            gd.setColor(colour);
        }
        if (drawable instanceof ColorDrawable) {
            ColorDrawable cd = (ColorDrawable) drawable;
            cd.setColor(colour);
        }
    }
}
```

This looks like :-

[image]

## Answer regarding :-

> I edited the code as you said I tried to do what you suggested at
>   first. And it worked perfectly but when I adjusted it to my code then
>   only one color appears, it changes depending on the last color or the
>   first one that should appear And why what I tried was problems? And
>   thank you very much for everything

I believe that your problem is that within `getView` (which is called individually for each item in the list (as is `bindView`) the View being the View for that position in the list) you are the looping through all the items/views and basically changing ALL items to be as per the last item.

**i.e. `getView` will be called (at least) 10 times for a list of 10 items. Each time it is called it is for the individual view/item being processed.**

I believe you need to change :-

```
if (convertview != null) {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);
        int Count = List.getCount();
        String[] Status = new String[Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < Count; ) {
            Cursor c = db.getCursorStatus(i);
            if (c != null) {
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    Status[i] = c.getString(0);

                }
            }

            String mStatus[] = new String[3];
        mStatus[0] = "Monetary_Expenditure";
        mStatus[1] = "Financial income";
        mStatus[2] = "Cancellation";


        boolean first = Status[i] != null && Status[i].equals(mStatus[1]);
        boolean second = Status[i] != null && Status[i].equals(mStatus[0]);

        if (Status[i] != null && Status[i].equals(mStatus[1])) {
            convertview.setBackgroundColor(colours[1]);
        } else if (Status[i] != null && Status[i].equals(mStatus[0])) {
            convertview.setBackgroundColor(colours[0]);
        }
        else {convertview.setBackgroundColor(0xFF555555);}

        i++;
    }
   }
```

To :-

```
    if (convertview != null) {
        Cursor csr = getCursor(); 
        String status = csr.getString(0);
        int colourindex = 0;
        if (status.equals("Financial income") {
            colourindex = 1;
        }
        if (status.equals("Cancellation") {
            colourindex = 2;
        }
        convertview.setBackgroundColor(colours[colourindex]);       
    }
```

- So you get the cursor using the CursorAdapters `getCursor()` method, the cursor will be positioned accordingly.
- You then extract the status for the item in the List for which the View is being built i.e. `getView()` is called for **every item in the list**. So if you have 10 items in the List `getView()` is called at least 10 times. You appear to consider that it is called just once.
- The colour index (0,1 or 2) is determined according to the status (column 0).
- The background colour is set according to the status for the specific Item in the list.

Comment: I edited the code as you said
I tried to do what you suggested at first. And it worked perfectly but when I adjusted it to my code then only one color appears, it changes depending on the last color or the first one that should appear And why what I tried was problems? And thank you very much for everything

Comment: @MenachemYarhi I've edited the answer (although I've not tested, so there may be the odd typing error)

Comment: @MenachemYarhi You will need to add a third colour or amend the code so that **`colourindex`** can only be 0 or 1, otherwise ***cancellation** status will fail with an index array error.

Comment: thanx, i edit the post Because I get this error: `android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1`

Comment: You did not change the code as I said. Remove the three lines you added. That is unless **status** is not in the Cursor for the list. In which case you would need to get the **status** for the row being processed i.e. you would extract the columns that could be passed to the getCursorStatus() method (however this should be a method that returns the status not a cursor, and if a cursor that cursor would need to be positioned before trying to get data from it).

Comment: Perhaps edit the question and add the code for the Database Helper (DatabaseHandler) and indicate the cursor that the adapter is using.

Comment: I deleted the lines and made a small change, and now there is no error. But always only the last line is red and it's strange because it gets too much Empty IF(This means that instead of information there is a ""
) and all of them have only the first option and it should not be that way

Comment: I suspect that column 0 (this first) column is not the status. After the line `String status = csr.getString(0);` add `Log.d("STATUS","The status for row " + Integer.toString(csr.getPosition()) + " is " + status`); The dit your question with the result and also add the Databasehandler class and indicate the cursor being used for the adapter.

Comment: Yes I know I did it. and the result has not changed sadly

Comment: You are moving the cursor to the next item **leave the cursor positioning alone** it will be positioned to the correct row just get the status from the appropriate column. If you added the line look at the log.

Comment: Thank you very much !!!! It works for me, I have more what a few small questions if you can

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162381/discussion-between-miket-and-menachem-yarhi).